# Raphael Linechart. Overwrite X Axis. Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'attr'

Tags: graphael

I try to update the Unix timestamp of a Raphael LineChart in a beautiful formatted date, but I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Object 0 has no method 'attr'

The code I'm using is the following :

```
  var progression = r.linechart(30, 0, 350, 300, x, y, options);

  console.log("Progression is %O", progression.axis[0].text.items);

  /* Overwrites the Axis label for display a formatted date instead of the Unix timestamp */
  $(progression.axis[0].text.items).each( function ( label, index ) {
      originalText = label.attr('text');
      newText = 'up';
      label.attr({'text': newText});
    });
```

It seems I can't modify the label, BUT the attribute exists, as shown on this printscreen...
The highlighted text is my Unix timestamp...

[image: Printscreen Chrome console]

I tried to modify directly the attribute but it it not possible... When I print label, it is only a string, not an object (?)

Comment: Is it possible to add a fiddle? I usually prefer my custom axis labels. It can be easily generated using chart.eachColumn.

Inside eachColumn, this.y, this.x along with this.value can be used to position text wherever you want on the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Object 0 has no method 'attr'

... because it is actually 'attrs'

[image]

Comment: Nope, sorry. It was the inversionof the arguements in the function that drive my crazy. I inverted label and index and it worked ;-) Solution is :

Comment: $(progression.axis[0].text.items).each( function ( index, label ) {
   console.log("label ",label);
      originalText = label.attr('text');
      newText = 'up';
      label.attr('text', newText);
    });